# Is it possible to activate an iPhone 4 without a SIM?

Tags: iphone, sim

So we bought an iPhone 4 from the Apple store. But we didn't get a micro-SIM as there are no PAYG tariffs on micro-SIM available.

Is there anyway to activate the device without getting hold of a SIM? I don't want to sign up to a contract just to develop with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [this excellent description](http://download809.mediafire.com/0y024w663fpg/ztyuzyt5jaz/MicroSIM+template.pdf) (PDF) to cut my normal SIM into microSIM format. It was very easy to follow and it works perfectly!

Comment: I did end up buying a Microsim cutter but this also works.

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you know somenone who owns an iPhone 4 already. Ask her/him for the micro SIM, put it into your device, activate your iPhone and give the micro SIM back to the other person.

Comment: This is what Apple told me to do. Just don't know anyone with one!!! Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is a PAYG SIM, you should note that micro-SIMs are physically the same as standard SIMs except for the shape of the plastic surrounding the chip. I think that with a bit of careful cutting you can trim away the excess plastic and use any PAYG SIM.

If you Google "trim micro sim" you'll find a [few](http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2010/05/sim-trim-cutting-card-down-to-microsim-size/) [blog](http://www.techradar.com/news/computing/apple/how-to-make-your-own-ipad-or-iphone-4-micro-sim-681020) [posts](http://blog.makezine.com/archive/2010/05/trim_your_sim_ftw.html) describing the process.

Comment: Thanks yea I've too just read that! Thing is, I don't want to destroy my current SIM, just want to activate this phone. I've just ordered a cheap micro SIM so I will try that. Just didn't want to wait! Thanks

Comment: In the UK you can typically buy a PAYG SIM from a supermarket or mobile phone shop for £10 or less. So you wouldn't have to wait long. I don't know how it works elsewhere.

Comment: o2 told me that they didn't sell them, but I've found one online! I will just have to wait! My iPhone 4 is doing a good job at being a paper weight for now!

Answer (score 0):

You could jailbraik the phone to activate it without the SIM card.